# UIPickerView Ghost Image

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am trying to use a picker view in my swift code which I get to run luckily. But every time I load the program my picker view creates a ghost image of itself. Why does that happen? Do I need to make any adjustments to my code?
[image: here]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewTwo: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerMenSplit: UIPickerView!

    //var menPickerSplit: [String] = [String] ()
    var menPickerSplit = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Connect Data:
        pickerMenSplit.delegate = self
        pickerMenSplit.dataSource = self

        //Input data into the Array:


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //the number of columns of data
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //the number of rows of data
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return menPickerSplit.count
    }

    //the data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return menPickerSplit[row]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your project? cmd+shift+k, if that doesn't work, try deleting your app from the simulator and then try to run it again.

Comment: i did the cleanup and it did not help. I have tried running the app on a completely new file and I noticed that on the original ViewController navigation pane it works fine, but if you create a second navigation pane with a new class, that is when the file starts acting differently. I am not sure what the issues might be but I am trying to figure out why on the second and third View Controllers I build that it creates these ghost images on the picker.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how I could fix this?